# Meteor enter key event

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client "simplified version" code needs to print "submitted" to the browser console when the keyboard enter key is touched/clicked but it does nothing.
Why and how to fix it? thx

```
Template.body.events({
  'submit #myForm': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');  //<=========
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    {{> index}}
  </form>
</body>

<template name="index">
  <div id="main">
    {{> content}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="content">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=whichOne}}
</template>

<template name="search">
  <input class="half" type="text" id="food" autocomplete="off">
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input section in the `search` template add listener to Enter key. Add this line:

```
onKeyPress={(event)=>{
    if(event.key == 'Enter'){
        // do whatever you like to do
    }
}}
```

Here is a tiny example: https://jsfiddle.net/kxooyb3z/